# PHP, MySQL Query not working

Tags: php, mysql, echo

Working on a small university project to develop a small php site. Seem to be having a couple of issues. I am a complete newbe when it comes to programming of any kind. I am literately cutting and pasting (From provided scripts) and trying to get things to come together in the way I require.

I seem to be having a problem collecting data from a database query, I already have one on the script which works perfectly. I am trying to add another, however can't seem to get this to work.

http://mkiddr.com/phptests/shopping/category.php?id=2

Currently the category.php is displaying all the products within the category. However I wish for it to also display the category description and you'll see in the following code how I've tried to do this:

```
 <?php
session_start();
include "conn.php";
include "header.php";

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $CategoryID = $_GET['id'];
    $q="SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products WHERE CategoryID=$CategoryID";
    $d="SELECT Desc FROM ProductCategories WHERE CategoryID=$CategoryID";

    $result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);

    $result2 = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$d);

    echo "<div>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        echo "<p><a href='product.php?id=".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</a></p>";
    }
    echo "<p>".$result2."</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
include "footer.php";
?>
```

Would appreciate some help!

**UPDATED CODE (Still not working)**

```
   <?php
   session_start();
   include "conn.php";
   include "header.php";

 if (isset($_GET['id'])){
$CategoryID = $_GET['id'];
$q="SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products WHERE CategoryID=$CategoryID";
$d="SELECT `Desc` FROM ProductCategories WHERE CategoryID=$CategoryID";

$result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);
$result2 = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$d);  

echo "<div>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    echo "<p><a href='product.php?id=".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</a></p>";
}
echo "</div>";
mysqli_free_result($result);

//Description
echo "<div>";
while ($result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    echo "<p>".$result2[0]."</p>";
   }

   }
  include "footer.php";
  ?>
```

Comment: Check the code in my post.

Answer (score 4):

One of the errors I've seen is the use of reserved keywords.

The reason why `$d` is not executing is because column `DESC` is a reserved keyword from `MYSQL`. You can delimite it with backtick or supply an alias on the table to make it work, eg

```
$d="SELECT `Desc` FROM ProductCategories WHERE CategoryID=$CategoryID";
```

OR

```
$d="SELECT a.Desc FROM ProductCategories a WHERE CategoryID=$CategoryID";
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Ahh fantastic this would make sense. 

However I seem to then receive the following error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /volume1/web/phptests/shopping/category.php on line 19

Comment: echo "<p>".$result2."</p>";

Comment: What are you expecting that to do? P.S. please start response with @barmar if you want me to notice it.

Comment: @bamar, apologies. It should be collecting the Categories Description from the database.... It should then be displaying this description based on the categories ID.

Comment: The new `while` loop in the UPDATE is overwriting `$result2` with the result of `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. So the second time through the loop it's no longer a result that can be used as an argument. Use a different variable, like `$row2`. And my name is Barmar, not Bamar, so I wasn't notified of your response. Use SO's name completion, then typos should be minimized.

Answer (score 1):

First remember to fetch the query into an array:

```
$result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
```

Since the query is saved into an associative array you should call it in that way 
`$result2['Desc']`

```
<?php
   session_start();
   include "conn.php";
   include "header.php";

 if (isset($_GET['id'])){
$CategoryID = $_GET['id'];
$q="SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products WHERE CategoryID=$CategoryID";
$d="SELECT `Desc` FROM ProductCategories WHERE CategoryID=$CategoryID";

$result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);
$result2 = mysql_fetch_assoc( mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$d) );  

echo "<div>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    echo "<p><a href='product.php?id=".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</a></p>";
}
echo "</div>";
mysqli_free_result($result);

//Description
echo "<div>";
          echo "<p>".$result2['Desc']."</p>";
echo "</div>";

   }
  include "footer.php";
  ?>
```

Comment: This is just plain wrong, `mysqli_fetch_row` does not return a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: That is true, my bad. I edited my answer with an assoc command.

Comment: Now your answer is no longer wrong, but it's still not a solution. `mysqli_fetch_array()` works fine the way he used it.

Comment: Perhaps its just me going blind Barmar. But i see no mysqli_fetch_array command in his code. I see him resulting his first query, but not his second query. Could you point to me where it is then.
Jonas

Comment: I thought you were telling him to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` _instead_ of `mysqli_fetch_row`.

Comment: Ah. No dear sir.
Perhaps you will withdraw your downvote then?